# Como o Maps desenha o poligno automaticamente quando se digita o nome do bairro?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Como o Google Maps desenha o polígono automaticamente quando digitamos o nome do de um bairro?**

Abaixo fiz uma pesquisa no maps pelo bairro [Colinas da Anhanguera](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Colinas+da+Anhanguera,+Santana+de+Parna%C3%ADba+-+SP/@-23.4529569,-46.875048,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x94cf0293e119e04b:0x493ec547a458c611!8m2!3d-23.4518803!4d-46.839816), Santana de Parnaíba - SP, o mesmo gerou esse [polígono](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Colinas+da+Anhanguera,+Santana+de+Parna%C3%ADba+-+SP/@-23.4529569,-46.875048,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x94cf0293e119e04b:0x493ec547a458c611!8m2!3d-23.4518803!4d-46.839816) automaticamente.

[image: Bairro Pesquisado: Colinas da Anhanguera]

Comment: Parece vagamente uma cabeça de cavalo ("Farei uma proposta que ele não poderá recusar"...). E o [mapa de São Paulo](http://www.mapas-sp.com/imagens/bairros-sp.jpg) parece uma girafa...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para criar um polígono precisamos conhecer a área a ser delimitada precisamos de coordenadas; se possuirmos as coordenadas que definirão o contorno do polígono o trabalho fica mais fácil; no nosso caso como não dispomos das coordenadas criar remos o perímetro da área a ser delimitada e então iremos obter as coordenadas. Para saber como criar um arquivo para exibição de maps com a API V3 do Google Maps acesse o artigo Criando um mapa de polígono com a API V3 do Google Maps.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com a ferramenta de desenho de linha selecionada basta desenhar o polígono desejado. Uma dica, como muitas vezes a área do polígono é extensa e precisamos nos mover melo mapa e dar zoom, o clique do mouse não pode ser utilizado para mover o mapa, pois cada clique com o mouse corresponde a um ponto do polígono a ser marcado;  assim sendo, utilize o mouse apenas para marcar os pontos do polígono, e o scrool para definir o zoom, a movimentação pelo mapa deve ser feita apenas pelas setas do teclado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este link mostra o procedimento por completo: http://www.sutel.com.br/blog/index.php/en/programacao/64-criando-um-poligono-area-delimitada-no-google-maps

Comment: Entendi, muito bom o artigo, a minha outra dúvida é como o Google Maps faz o polígono automaticamente?

_Ex_: _Pesquise algum bairro no Maps e veja o polígono gerado_.